# How to read params from Transloadit upon successful upload to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

i am using [Transloadit](http://transloadit.com/) to process and store my pic to amazon s3. The upload works fine, however upon successful redirect back to my app i get an error when trying to access one of the vales from the hash of params sent by transloadit.

```
<%= params[:transloadit][:ok] %>
```

The error returned is

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

and the hash of params looks like this:

```
 {"transloadit"=>"{\"ok\":\"ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED\",
\"message\":\"The assembly was successfully completed.\",
\"assembly_id\":\".........\",
\"assembly_url\":\"http://api2.donnie.transloadit.com/assemblies/....\",
\"bytes_received\":351697,
\"bytes_expected\":351697,.........}
```

I am using the gem [transloadit/rails-sdk](https://github.com/transloadit/rails-sdk) for easy integration into my app. On their github page they say and i quote:

"If you want to use the automatic transload parameter decoding, you have to include the Transloadit::Rails::ParamsDecoder module into your controller

```
class YourController
  include Transloadit::Rails::ParamsDecoder
end
```

that way the param[:transloadit] is automatically decoded for you, if it exists"

I am not sure what they mean by this (even if i include this into my controller i get an error with a different set of params). **What is the purpose of this line?**

**All i need is to access the params[:transloadit][:ok] parameter. How can i get hold of this parameter? thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. If you use key names instead of symbols, it might help. I'm not sure why, but that's what I had to do. Try `params["transloadit"]["ok"]` or some variation of that.

Comment: thanks that seemed to work, Why does when i supply key names?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm actually an iOS developer trying to learn rails myself. ;-)